# GridView with Jump to Page DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

Hi I want to have a DropDownList outside of my GridView that displays a list of page numbers.  When the user clicks on a page number, the GridView should go to that page.  I am able to populate the DropDownList, but it's not working with the GridView

Here is my GridView and DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPaging_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList> &nbsp;of 
         <%=GridView1.PageCount%>


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid" GridLines="Both" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#990033" Width="1000px" 
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
         <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchID" HeaderText="Batch ID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="intBatchID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="vcharName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dtmScheduled" HeaderText="Date Scheduled" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="dtmScheduled" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchPriorityLevel" 
            HeaderText="Priority Level" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="intBatchPriorityLevel" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />        
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my code behind

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < GridView1.PageCount; cnt++)
        {
            int curr = cnt + 1;

            ListItem item = new ListItem(curr.ToString());

            if (cnt == GridView1.PageIndex)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }

            ddlPageNumber.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }

    protected void ddlPaging_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPageNumber.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you update the `PageIndex` you need to rebind the grid, like this:

```
protected void ddlPaging_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPageNumber.SelectedIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Since you are dynamically building the drop down list items for the page numbers, then you need to re-build them whenever a post back to the server happens or whenever the grid is rebound, like this:

```
private void BuildPageNumbers()
{
    ddlPageNumber.Items.Clear();

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < GridView1.PageCount; cnt++)
    {
        int curr = cnt + 1;

        ListItem item = new ListItem(curr.ToString());

        if (cnt == GridView1.PageIndex)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }

        ddlPageNumber.Items.Add(item);

    }
}
```

Now in your `DataBound` and `Page_Load` events, you can call this method, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildPageNumbers();
}

protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    BuildPageNumbers();
}
```

Comment: I tried the databind, and it's still not working, but I realized that neither is my pagesize drop down, nor is paging working inside the GridView.  I am getting the error message Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList. When I click on the numeric paging.  Any idea?

Comment: @hollyquinn - are you re-binding the grid on every `Page_Load`?

Comment: Karl no I'm not.  Should I be?

Comment: @hollyquinn - well part of your problem is that your drop down list of page numbers is getting destroyed on post back from itself, because you are dynamically building the drop down list items in the `DataBound` event of the grid, which only happens after the grid has been populated via `.DataBind()`. So I think you a few issues happening at once.

Comment: Do you know what I should do to fix it?

Comment: It works now with the paging inside the GridView.  When I click on the numeric paging the number in the dropdownlist changes to the page I'm currently on, but when I make a selection in the dropdownlist it does nothing.

Comment: @hollyquinn - if you put a break point on the line `GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPageNumber.SelectedIndex;`, does it get hit? If so, then what is the value of `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: It wasn't hitting the code.  I took it out of my MasterPage and put it in a blank page, and it runs fine.  I'm thinking there may be something wrong with the masterpage.  I'm unsure though why it wouldn't hit the code in the page that is using a masterpage.  Thanks for your help though.  You answered my questions.